# Updating a plot title using LaTeX in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, printf, latex

I'm attempting to update a plot title using the following code in MATLAB,

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:.05:1);
n=400;
for j=1:n
d=j/200;
Z=abs((X-1i*Y).^(d));
surf(X,Y,Z);
t=sprintf('$$f(z)=z^{%%d}$$', d, 'interpreter','latex');
title(t);
xlabel('Re(z)');
ylabel('Im(z)');
zlabel('|f(z)|');
zlim([0 1]);
pause(.001);
end
```

but the end result isn't so good. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf` does not interpret strings as latex input. `title` does, however.

You need to specify the interpreter for `title` instead.

Here's a short example:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:.05:1);
n=10;
for j=1:n
  d=j/200;
  Z=abs((X-1i*Y).^(d));
  surf(X,Y,Z);
  t=sprintf('$$f(z)=z^{%f}$$', d); % move interpreter specification to title
  title(t,  'interpreter','latex');
  xlabel('Re(z)');
  ylabel('Im(z)');
  zlabel('|f(z)|');
  zlim([0 1]);
  pause(.001);
end
```